# Why I can't bind (**) operator

Tags: f#

In f# i can easily bind (+) or (*) operators. Why can't I do the same with (**)?

```
> let s = (+);;
val s : (int -> int -> int)

> let f = (**);;
  let f = (**);;
  ------------^^
C:\Users\mqrx84\AppData\Local\Temp\stdin(4,13): error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in binding
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `(*` `*)` are used for multi line comments. You need to separate the parentheses from the operator with whitespace e.g. `let f = ( ** );;`

> To define other operators that begin with *, whitespace must follow
>   the opening parenthesis; otherwise (* is interpreted as the start of a
>   comment: let ( *+* ) x y = (x + y)

From the spec - http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/

Comment: So simple :) Now I'm waiting for the 10 minutes cooldown to pass so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki The compiler seems to handle that as a special case with its own token `LPAREN_STAR_RPAREN`